# Restore oracle xe problem

Tags: oracle, ora-12560

I am trying to restore oracle XE by clicking (run as administrator) **Restore Database** from Start menu -> All Programms ->Oracle Database 10g Express Edition. After entering yes to the confirmation question the error messages appear.

Messages are:

RMAN-00554: Initialization of internal recovery manager package failed

RMAN-04005: error from target database:

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Error:
Restore of the database failed.RMAN Error-  could not startup dummy instance.


The tnsnames.ora file is in place,the OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener services are running and I am able to connect to xe with sqlplus.
What is strange is this problem happened to me a few days ago, after I restarted the machine for a few times it workd and I was able to rstore.This time I couldn't make it work at all.

If it helps,I am running win 7 and I have Oracle 10g client and Oracle 11g client installed on my machine.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Ok, one of my colleagues had this idea to uninstall the oracle express and install it again and that solved my problem! I still don't know the cause, but I am able to restore the db after reinstalling oracle xe.

Comment: You could put your solution in an "answer" and accept it if you want - future generations will thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your database server configured for DHCP? If so, you'll need to install the [Microsoft Loopback Adapter.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/reqs.htm#BABGCEAI) Your reinstallation may have just temporarily made the problem go away.